# How to send float numbers from a C# application to a C++ application?

Tags: c#, c++, ipc, interprocess

I have two applications:

1.: C# GUI application written in VisualStudio 2013.

2.: C++ GUI application written in VisualStudio 2013.

I would like to send float numbers from application #1 to application #2.

(In other words: If the C# app. calculates a float number (e.g.: 12.32) then I would like to see this number on the standard output written by the C++ application.)

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? Is there any Windows API, or common-memory-address-thing, etc. to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmmm... There's some way's to do it (what i know) :

- Using Sockets
- Using [Shared Memory](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/salvapatuel/2009/06/08/working-with-memory-mapped-files-in-net-4/)
- Using Read Write Files
- Using P\Invoke to [Change Controls Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11748901/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-another-programs-window)
- Using [IPC Channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication)

If i want do this on GUI Applcation i'll choose P\Invoke but if i want do something background i'll choose IPC Channels or Shared Memory (IPC Channels is better)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using any kind of inter-process communication mechanism. The simplest one might be anonymous pipes. You will find how to use anonymous pipes [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx) in C++ and [there](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762927(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#.

Answer (score 1):

I assume both applications are running at the same time.  I would do a local transfer using sockets or I assume that the c++ application just catches the data from the C# app so you can return it as a data object and pass that to the spawning C++ app as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

One of the easiest ways is to dump the values to a file in C# then pick them up in C++.

note: This method is not the most reliable/fastest and may not be best for enterprise product but for a quick one time need this should work fine.

Save the output to a file...

```
using System.IO;

class ConsoleApplication {
    static void Main()
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(File.Open("temp.dat", FileMode.Create)))
        {
            writer.Write(1.2345F);
        }
    } }
```

Then read it in using c++... [(Source is here)](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/257842/How-Read-Float-value-from-Binary-File)

```
#include <iostream>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *r_file = NULL;
    float fd_value = 0;

    r_file = fopen("temp.dat", "rb");
    if (NULL == r_file)
        return 0;

    fread(&fd_value, 1, sizeof(fd_value), r_file);
    fclose(r_file);


    printf("fd_value = %f\n", fd_value);
    return 0;
}
```