# qt push button send data to qtextcursor to type

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to know if the following is possible as I have been searching but haven't found anything that answers my question. The closest i've got it QTextCursor typing on the a QTextDocument. (Not what I want).

What I am looking for is a method of typing data wherever the textcursor is on screen, (even if its not in the qt app window), once a qpushbutton has triggered a 'clicked' event. I have set the push button up and push button event up. I just havent found a way to get the data to type to the screen.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: could you explain the part that you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depend on the platform, and it's not related to Qt, for example with windows you could see the answer of Xavier Poinas at this link [Insert text into the textbox of another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539187/insert-text-into-the-textbox-of-another-application)

And if you just want floating text, you could use QLabel without parent, place your QLabel with setGeometry or move at the point given by QCursor::pos() or QCursor::pos(const QScreen *).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Following your recommendations I have been able to get it working for Microsoft platforms.